# Gulp concat in order

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-concat

I'd like to create a sass file using GulpJS. The main issue is that `gulp.src()` has a specific order that I want to respect when concatenation.

My task that doesn't work...

```
gulp.task('createGlobalScss', function(done) {
  return gulp.src([
    'sass/colors.scss',
    'sass/theme.scss',
    'sass/settings.scss',
    'sass/functions.scss',
    'sass/mixins.scss',
    'sass/components/**/settings.scss',
    'sass/theme.scss',
    'sass/components/**/*.scss'
  ])
  .pipe(concat('globalScss.scss'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
  done();
});
```

Issue : The result is disordered and I don't want to use `@import` from SASS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [gulp-order](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-order)

> The gulp plugin gulp-order allows you to reorder a stream of files using the same syntax as of gulp.src.

Your task could then be structured as such...

```
var order = require('gulp-order');

gulp.task('createGlobalScss', function() {
  return gulp.src('sass/**/*.scss')
    .pipe(order([
      'sass/colors.scss',
      'sass/theme.scss',
      'sass/settings.scss',
      'sass/functions.scss',
      'sass/mixins.scss',
      'sass/components/**/settings.scss',
      'sass/theme.scss',
      'sass/components/**/*.scss'
    ], { base: __dirname }))
    .pipe(concat('globalScss.scss'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./'));
});
```

You can also remove `done` here as you're not needing the explicit async callback in this case. Also notice there is a [`base` option](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-order#base) which I needed to specify for this to work as expected.

---

Per our discussion below, [here is a proof of concept](https://github.com/scniro/Gulp-concat-in-order) which demonstrates this working with the proposed solution...

Comment: It doesn't work in `golbalScss.scss`, it is not start by the content of `sass/colors.scss` with `gulp-order`.

Comment: What file is `$badge-bg` found in? Looks like bootstrap to me

Comment: @tonymx227 edited, try adding `sass/**/*.scss` to the end of your order array if you have any other files that are found there. Does the order you have listed here explicitly identify all of the files you have?

Comment: It doesn't work too with `sass/**/*.scss`, the order of the array is not respected... I think `gulp-order` change the order of the array...

Comment: @tonymx227 I indeed also saw this not working as expected on my end with a sample. I edited my answer with the optional `{ base: __dirname }` and it's now working as expected. Can you try this option and let me know?

Comment: Also scrap the last suggestion of the catch-all at the end and just try `base`. I'll throw my sample up on github that proves this

Comment: Check out my [sample proof project](https://github.com/scniro/Gulp-concat-in-order) for this

Comment: @tonymx227 hey were you able to check out the sample project I threw together and figure this out yesterday?